# TinyMCE - Adding a Key Binding CNRTL-S COMMAND-S to call an AJAX save Function

Tags: javascript, tinymce, textarea

I'd like to learn how to bind a CNRTL-S or COMMAND-S to call a function that I have on my page which AJAX saves the textarea content's

How can I bind those two commands? I used to use the following when it was just a textarea, but since adding TinyMCE it no longer works. Suggestions?

```
// Keybind the Control-Save
jQuery('#text_area_content').bind('keydown', 'ctrl+s',function (evt){
saveTextArea();
    return false;
});
 // Keybind the Meta-Save Mac
jQuery('#text_area_content').bind('keydown', 'meta+s',function (evt){
saveTextArea();
    return false;
});
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use a custom method for saving, i declare my saving function in the tinymce.init method

```
tinyMCE.init({
        // General options
        mode: "none",
        /* some standard init params, plugins, ui, custom styles, etc */            


        save_onsavecallback: saveActiveEditor,
        save_oncancelcallback: cancelActiveEditor
    });
```

Then i define the function itself

```
function saveActiveEditor() {
     var activeEditor = tinyMCE.activeEditor;
     var saveUrl = "http://my.ajax.path/saveStuff";
     var idEditor = activeEditor.id;
     var contentEditor = activeEditor.getContent();
     /* the next line is for a custom language listbox to edit different locales */
     var localeEditor = activeEditor.controlManager.get('lbLanguages').selectedValue;

     $.post(saveUrl ,
            { id: idEditor, content: contentEditor, locale: localeEditor },
            function(results) {
                if (results.Success) {
                    // switch back to display instead of edit
                    return false;
                }
                else {
                    activeEditor.windowManager.alert('Error saving data');
                    return false;
                }
            },
            'json'
        );
        return false;
 }
```

Don't forget to `return false` to override the default save action that posts back your data to the server.

---

edit to add: i only let the user change one tinymce instance at a time. You may want to change the locating the current instance to something else :)

---

edit #2: TinyMce already catches the Ctrl+s binding to process the data. Since it also cleans up html and is able to handle specific rules it's given when saving, the solution i propose is to plug your way of saving in tinyMce instead of fully overriding the Ctrl+s binding

Comment: I'm looking to save with key bindings. Where in your answer is there anything about keybindings?

Comment: Tinymce already catches the Ctrl+s combination. So instead of letting it save by posting back the results, we override its default behavior using an ajax call. Since tinyMCE does lots of things at save time, it's better to override only what's needed and let it take care of the whole cleanup/on-the-fly edits, etc...

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that the tinymce iframe does not delegate the events to the parent window. You can define custom_shortcuts in tinymce and/or use the following syntax:

```
// to delegate it to the parent window i use
var create_keydown_event = function(combo){
    var e = { type : 'keydown' }, m = combo.split(/\+/);
    for (var i=0, l=m.length; i<l; i++){
        switch(m[i]){
            case 'ctrl': e.metaKey = true;
            case 'alt': case 'shift': e[m[i] + 'Key'] = true; break;
            default : e.charCode = e.keyCode = e.which = m[i].toUpperCase().charCodeAt(0);
        }
    }
    return e;
}

var handler = function(){

  setTimeout(function(){
    var e = create_keydown_event(combo);
    window.parent.receiveShortCutEvent(e);
  }, 1);
}

//ed.addShortcut(combo, description, handler);
ed.addShortcut('ctrl+s', 'save_shortcut', handler);
```

in the parent window you need a function receiveShortCutEvent which will sort out what to do with it

Comment: This doesn't seem to work. Where does it live? how does itknow which tinymce instance to look for etc. Seems like a hack no?

Comment: Where do you put ed.addShortcut?

Comment: You put it in a plugin. You should place this code inside the onInit of the plugin. Handler:   ed.onInit.add(ed){...} , but you can reffer to the editor from outside a plugin to using  ed = tinymce.activeEditor: